# Syncing time between two machines

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, time

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I have two machines, one is a master(running `roscore`) and the second is a slave.
Until now I set manually the time for each computer. Now, I want to do set it automatically.
I searched a lot of options in the internet but I couldn't configure well the configurations.
I tried `chrony`,`ntp`,`ntpdate` and nothing happened. I think that our ISP is blocking the access for these ntp servers.
I also tried to get the time from the ntp server of our ISP but I think that I don't understand very well this subject.
I want to know if there is a simple tutorial how I can take the ros time from the master to be on the slave machine. I prefer to not use a ntp server. I believe that there is a simple way to do that.

I will happy if someone can give me a link or instructions for that problem.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338970/syncing-time-between-two-machines/) by [Aviad](https://answers.ros.org/users/34139/aviad/) on ROS Answers with karma: 96 on 2019-12-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-12-02**:\

> I want to know if there is a simple tutorial how I can take the ros time from the master to be on the slave machine. I prefer to not use a ntp server.

that's exactly what chrony <del>does</del> can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So, I tried again with `chrony` and I found a simple explanation how to do that. Now it works.
If someone want the link for that is here:
[chrony_setup](https://answers.ros.org/question/298821/tf-timeout-with-multiple-machines/)

---

Originally posted by [Aviad](https://answers.ros.org/users/34139/aviad/) with karma: 96 on 2019-12-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1